# Why are the control points/inner lines on the inside of cup leaking out when I zoom out?

Tags: mesh

Zoomed out view: https://i.postimg.cc/9fzndvY0/image.png

When i zoom in: https://i.postimg.cc/3JHHFJqq/image.png

Wireframe view: https://i.postimg.cc/gj5JJ9sh/image.png

Blender file (the cup is on layer 2) : https://www95.zippyshare.com/v/2nyeVtve/file.html

Pretty sure I am doing something wrong here, I just don't know what it  is.

Could some help me identify it?

Comment: I think it's a bug (feature maybe?) of orthographic view. Set the clip end distance to a smaller value (it's in the view tab, press N if you can't find it), and the issue should be gone.

Comment: whew.. i thought i was doing something wrong here. Clipping value 600 sealed the deal

Answer (score -1):

> Set the clip end distance to a smaller value (it's in the view tab,
>   press N if you can't find it)

Thanks @sacrish

Comment: You're welcome.